# How to print variable's new value after it has been changed

Tags: c#

If I have a program where x = 2 and I subtracted x by 1, making x = 1. Is there any way to make it so that whenever x will be printed in the program, it will print 1?

```cs
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x = 2;
            Console.WriteLine(x-1);
            Console.WriteLine(x); //make x's new value 1
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `x-1` takes the value of `x` and subtracts 1, but doesn't store that value back into `x`. You might want `x = x - 1`, equivalently `x--`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to store the calculation to the variable

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x = 2;
            Console.WriteLine(x);//will print 2
            x = x-1; //applying calculation and storing to same variable
            Console.WriteLine(x); //make x's new value 1 : Done
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write

```
x--; 
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

That's how you change the value of a variable - you have to assign it a new value.

Alternatively you can write `x = x - 1;` longhand instead of using the decrement (`--`) operator.

What you did in your version was to create some output which was the result of x-1, but that doesn't change the original value of x, it just uses x in another calculation.

Comment: what if I wanted to subtract it by 3 or 5, would I just add more decrements?

Comment: well you could write `x = x-3;` for example to directly subtract that amount. You don't have to subtract 1 at a time...unless of course you want to show each change on screen in between. it's not clear what exactly you need. But it seems like maybe you'd benefit from some basic study of the maths operators in C#, and about how variable assignment works.

Answer (score 0):

You are Displaying the Correct answer.
2 - 1 will Display 1. But u arent changing the Variable or even touching it. You are just using it for a Reference to Calculate what is x - 1?
Displaying only X now will Display 2 as it has NOT been changed.

Setting (Changing the Value of a Variable) is not (normaly) possible inside a Function. There are Functions which take ref params. Which will work with its memory.

You simply need a one-liner.
x = x - 1 **translated** the value of x is set to the value of x - 1.

it seems much for a simple calculation to require a whole line as it is. But programming will always be one of these things where u have to think **literall**

This whole problem is a great example for [Rubberducking](https://rubberduckdebugging.com).
think about it literall... line for line what exactly happens and why should it not work?

Comment: It's worth noting that rubberducking, while a great technique, only really works if you understand the syntax of the code and its meaning. From the way the first sentence of the question is written, it appears the main issue here is that OP assumed that `x-1` would change the value of `x` itself. So if they rubber-ducked the code they'd be likely to be make the same assumption again and therefore be unable to spot the problem. Rubberducking is more useful for bigger logical issues in the code, rather than for learning basic syntax.